# tf installation problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have been trying to start working with tf.
I followed this tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf

But I get this error

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource turtle_tf
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

when I try to run

```
rosdep install turtle_tf rviz
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55050/tf-installation-problem/) by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason for this is that ROS is not able to find turtlesim package. Either package is not installed  path to ros package directory is not correctly defined. Try command "roscd turtlesim" and see whether ur directed to turtlesim folder.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on 2013-02-12**:
Thank you. the "roscd turtlesim" is working correctly! but I still have the problem :(

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-12**:
Sorry check for "turtle_tf" pacakge instead of turtlesim..

**Comment by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on 2013-02-12**:
There is no such package "turtle_tf". I had to install its stack first using this line:     sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-geometry-tutorials. Now it's working